# Veronica won't walk around with me anymore

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

After I get out of the Hidden Valley bunker after trying to convince the elder and kill the four Brotherhood of Steel people waiting for me and Veronica there, Veronica just stands where she was when the fight ended.

I have tried telling her to wait and then to follow. That didn't work. I also tried dismissing her and finding her again. That didn't work either. What can I do?

Comment: It's probably because you forgot to wish her today a happy women's day.

Comment: Go get some flowers, maybe she'll excuse you. :p

Comment: Well, she DOES like dresses, so maybe a suit of Formal Wear will do the trick. Or at least, you will learn an Unarmed technique. Try fast traveling to another place after telling her to follow you. If that doesn't work either, I think you will have to load a previous save.

Comment: Can you try the tips from this thread: https://steamcommunity.com/app/22380/discussions/0/490125103627546553/? Don't know if this is the same problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it seems like a stretch but try this:

Travel to Gibsons shack (the one from her quest) and use the terminal on the floor.Click on download research notes and she should magically reappear talking about what technology to go after. Just choose whichever one to make her a follower once again

Answer (score 1):

If the Gibson's Shack fix does not work, you can use console commands to break her surge of consciousness.

From the [Fallout New Vegas wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Veronica_Santangelo#Bugs):

> At Hidden Valley, she may glitch and stay at the intercom and the door
>   to the bunker will become locked. The following
>   commands can be used to fix this glitch: *prid 000e32a9* then *SayTo
>   player HVVeronicaEnter*.

and

> Sometimes she will randomly stop following the player after
>   accessing her inventory. The following commands can
>   be used to fix this glitch: *prid 000e32a9*, *resurrect 1*, *disable*,
>   finally followed by *enable*.

Answer (score -1):

make her craft something it worked for me